# Can't able to perform button click and combo box selection changed in WinRT MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

**UPDATE 1 :** You can download the sample project from [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9E70869A1583FA52!892&authkey=!AHEXR2PtckK9gJM).

Can you please help me to find the error in my code. I can't able to assign item source to combo box as well as button click event in WinRT app. I am using MVVM and [MetroEventToCommand](http://metroeventtocommand.codeplex.com/). I am new to MVVM concept, so please answer my silly question.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="Click Here">
        <mvvm:EventToCommandManager.Collection>
            <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}" Event="Click"/>
        </mvvm:EventToCommandManager.Collection>
    </Button>

    <ComboBox x:Name="FontsCombo" Height="50" Width="150" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFont}"  ItemsSource="{Binding fonts}"  />

    <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{Binding SelectedFont}"/>
</Grid>

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new VM();
}

public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public RelayCommand ButtonClickCommand { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _fonts = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> fonts
    {
        get { return _fonts; }
        set
        {
            _fonts = value;
            if (null != PropertyChanged)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("fonts"));
            }
        }
    }

    private string _SelectedFont = "";
    public string SelectedFont
    {
        get { return _SelectedFont; }
        set
        {
            // Some logic here
            _SelectedFont = value;
            if (null != PropertyChanged)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedFont"));
            }

        }
    }
    public VM()
    {
        fonts.Add("Arial");
        fonts.Add("Courier New");
        fonts.Add("Times New Roman");
        ButtonClickCommand = new RelayCommand(Click);
    }

    private void Click()
    {
        new Action(async () => await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Testing dialog").ShowAsync()).Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Event ItemsSource for combobox doesn't work? Could you post all the MainPage.xaml here?

Comment: BTW: new Action(async () => await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Testing dialog").ShowAsync()).Invoke(); --- it blowed my mind

Comment: Combo box is not getting ItemsSource and button click doesn't work. Please see the sample [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9E70869A1583FA52!892&authkey=!AHEXR2PtckK9gJM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the SelectedItem, you didn't specify the Mode=TwoWay :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="FontsCombo" Height="50" Width="150" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFont, Mode=TwoWay}"  ItemsSource="{Binding fonts}"  />
```

EDIT 
I found the solution :

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public RelayCommand ButtonClickCommand { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _fonts;
    public ObservableCollection<string> fonts
    {
        get { return _fonts; }
        set
        {
            _fonts = value;
            if (null != PropertyChanged)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("fonts"));
            }
        }
    }

    private string _SelectedFont;
    public string SelectedFont
    {
        get { return _SelectedFont; }
        set
        {
            // Some logic here
            _SelectedFont = value;
            if (null != PropertyChanged)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedFont"));
            }

        }
    }
    public VM()
    {
        this.fonts = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        fonts.Add("Arial");
        fonts.Add("Courier New");
        fonts.Add("Times New Roman");
        ButtonClickCommand = new RelayCommand(Click);
    }

    private void Click()
    {
        new Action(async () => await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Testing dialog").ShowAsync()).Invoke();
    }
}
```

If I instance fonts in the constructor, the UX is not freezing anymore.

Comment: Not working, I have uploaded my [project](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9E70869A1583FA52!892&authkey=!AHEXR2PtckK9gJM) please have a look

Comment: When I try your project, the UX is freeze. Is it on your project too ?

Comment: Yes, I can't click on button and also can't open combo box

Comment: still not working :( see the [sample](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9E70869A1583FA52!893&authkey=!AHmjCMT9GYZPKqU)

Comment: I forgot to tell you : replace the Grid by a StackPanel ! In your project, the Textblock is on the Grid & Button. So you can use controls behind it

Comment: OMG, I did the silly mistake. The `TextBlock` was creating problem by covering the whole page, thanks Joffrey for your help.